# Visualising dot product P.l in Projective geometry

Tags: projective-geometry, homogeneous-equation

I am trying to understand how the following identity in homogeneous coordinates comes about and how to visualise the two multiplying parts $P$ and $l$ in the $3$D cartesian coordinates. Are they orthogonal to each other in order for the dot product to be zero. Can you show it in a picture?

> Since any non-zero multiple of $l$ defines the same line, it is useful to consider $l$ as a vector of which only the direction matters. Let $p=(u,v,w)$ be a point in homogeneous coordinates. Then in order for $p$ to lie on the same line, the dot product of $p$ and $l$ must vanish, that is,
> $$p\cdot l = 0$$

My understanding is shown in the picture below.

[image]

More background can be found here:

> We have seen that a point $(x,y)$ in the Cartesian plane has homogeneous coordinates $t(x,y,1)$, $t\neq0$. These coordinates would correspond to a line through the origin (excluded) if they were Cartesian coordinates in the $3$-dimensional space. When homogeneous coordinates are "viewed" as Cartesian coordinates, the dimensions of the geometric object they describe "increase" by one.
>
> The geometry of a line in the Cartesian plane is reviewed in Appendix A. It has a general equation $ax+by+c=0$. Suppose $(u,v,w)$ are the homogeneous coordinates of a point $(x,y)$ on the line; hence $x=\frac{u}{w}$ and $y=\frac{v}{w}$. Substituting $x$ and $y$ in the line equation and multiplying through by $w$, yields the conditions for $(u,v,w)$ to be the homogeneous coordinates of a point on the line:
> $$au+bv+cw=0$$
> The above equation is known as the *homogeneous line equation*. The line is uniquely specified by the coefficients $a,b$, and $c$, or any multiple $ra,rb$, and $rc$ with $r\neq0$. Therefore it is natural to specify the line by the homogeneous coordinates
> $$l=(a,b,c)$$

Comment: Equation (5) in the reference you provided shows exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: In the future, please take the time to enter important parts of your question as text instead of linking to pictures of it. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, nor do they show up in summaries. You can find a quick reference for formatting mathematical expressions in MathJax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint: Consider points and lines in $\mathbb R^3$ that are on the plane $z=1$ instead of on the $x$-$y$ plane.